# iTextSharp: "The document has no pages" when using ColumnText

Tags: itext

The following code throws "The document has no pages"

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        document.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

        using (var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream))
        {
            document.Open();

            PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

            ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(pdfContentByte);
            columnText.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 100, 20);
            columnText.AddElement(new Paragraph("Sample text", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20)));
            columnText.Go();

            document.Close();
        }
    }

    byte[] pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();

    // ...
}
```

How am I supposed to use `ColumnText` and `DirectContent` if this is not the way to do it?

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.3

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `columnText.Go()`? And have you tried with a more loosely fitting column?

Comment: I will try both @mkl

Comment: Indeed it seems I needed a moer loosely fitting column....